# Native app window in electron DOM element

Tags: javascript, window, electron, native

I wonder if it is possible to render a native application in an HTML element inside electron.

**As example:**

Render the Windows Media Player window in an DOM element.
So i can control the whole player, but see no native window, except my electron app.

Similar to an iframe/webview but with native applications

For better understanding i create a example image.
In the `<div>` is the rendered Window displayed, the `<button>'s` are "normal" HTML elements.[image]

Comment: this is nearly not possible.

Comment: I don't see how you can do this. You'll want to control it some other way. The button would need to communicate to the application via some API